# Position widgets in Column with different alignments

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following widget tree:

[image]

The `ListView` has `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` and `2` children. The `Column` has `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` with `3` children. The `2nd` child is significantly wider than the `1st` and `3rd` hence it determines the width of the column. How can I make the `1st` widget in the column left aligned? Currently all three widgets are centered horizontally as per the `crossAxisAlignment` of the `Column`.

Here's the layout of the column:

[image]

As expected all three children of the `Column` get positioned in the center of it. I need to make the first one left aligned.

[image]

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10,
                  ),
                  child: _composeCard(),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _composeCard() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Expanded(
          child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          boxShadow: [
            _composeShadow(dy: 2, blur: 8),
            _composeShadow(dy: 0, blur: 1),
          ],
        ),
        child: Material(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: InkWell(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Text("Header"), // I want to push this widget to the left
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text("Body: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text("Footer"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  BoxShadow _composeShadow({
    required double dy,
    required double blur,
    double spread = 0,
  }) {
    return BoxShadow(
      color: const Color(0xFFDBDBDB),
      offset: Offset(0, dy),
      spreadRadius: spread,
      blurRadius: blur,
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have described the question well enough, Can you include issue reproducible code-snippiet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to work.
You have to set a width for the item extend in your list, then you can use a row.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 2,
              itemExtent: 300,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10,
                  ),
                  child: _composeCard(),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _composeCard() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              boxShadow: [
                _composeShadow(dy: 2, blur: 8),
                _composeShadow(dy: 0, blur: 1),
              ],
            ),
            child: Material(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              child: InkWell(
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text("Header"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      const Text("Body: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      const Text("Footer"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  BoxShadow _composeShadow({
    required double dy,
    required double blur,
    double spread = 0,
  }) {
    return BoxShadow(
      color: const Color(0xFFDBDBDB),
      offset: Offset(0, dy),
      spreadRadius: spread,
      blurRadius: blur,
    );
  }
}
```

***Edit:***
I have an alternative solution if you can't use the fixed itemExtend, you could use `Stack` instead of `Column`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kPaddingPage),
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: kPaddingItemH,
                    right: kPaddingItemH,
                  ),
                  child: _composeCard(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _composeCard(double maxWidth) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              boxShadow: [
                _composeShadow(dy: 2, blur: 8),
                _composeShadow(dy: 0, blur: 1),
              ],
            ),
            child: Material(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              child: InkWell(
                child: Container(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text("Header"),
                          //other elements
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Text(""),
                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Text("Body: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"),
                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Text("Footer"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  BoxShadow _composeShadow({
    required double dy,
    required double blur,
    double spread = 0,
  }) {
    return BoxShadow(
      color: const Color(0xFFDBDBDB),
      offset: Offset(0, dy),
      spreadRadius: spread,
      blurRadius: blur,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works but unfortunately `itemExtent` sets effectively the width of the column - this can't be used as the widget determining the width of the column (the one with Lorem ipsum) should be assumed that may have a different width depending on the Locale, e.g. for certain languages the copy would have a different length hence the `itemExtent` would likely break.

Comment: Ok, can you specify more detailed what you need? You can change the itemExtend depending on your device, locale or anything you want. If you don't make the width a fix value, your item may get larger then your screen when the text gets longer.

Comment: This sample code mimics an app in prod. The equivalent view of the Body view is assumed to have a varied width depending on the used Locale. It is ok to assume that text would get longer, in practice it never will. The rules are: Body view width always > Header's and Footer's. Body view width needs to drive the width of the column. Header view needs to be left aligned. Footer view needs to be centered horizontally. Does this make sense?

Comment: I am trying to determine if there is a way to avoid `itemExtent: Platform.localeName == "some_local" ? 300 : 200`. In comparison to Android there is so many ways to achieve what I am after, yet Flutter seems somewhat restricted. I suppose that's to do with the single pass layout.

Comment: I edited my answer. You should give the Stack-Widget a try if the width has to change with your text length.

Comment: I am accepting your answer although that `TextView("")` to push down the body seems a hack. Is there no other way to arrange the widget tree?

Comment: Maybe somebody else knows a better solution, i also struggle with this limitations in flutter very often.